# Flutter Save a LIST of data to FireStore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple Shopping Cart App. The cart is a List of a model called "CartItem"

```
 List<CartItem> _cart= [];
```

and the Cart Model:

```
     class CartItem{
          String name;
          double singlePrice;
          double quantity;
     
   CartItem({
            this.name,
            this.singlePrice,
            this.quantity
        } );
```

After adding products to the cart, How can I save the entire Cart in Firestore?
for Example, lets say I have an OrderID. I want to have each CartItem as a document inside the OrderID collection. So if the user has 10 items in the cart, there will be 10 documents inside that orderID.

Please help! I've been at this for days now!!
Thank you!

Comment: If you want to learn how to add data to Firestore, start with the documentation.  If you have code that isn't working the way you expect, your question should show that code and explain what's wrong.  https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/

Comment: Im sorry. I know how to handle basic firebase transactions. My question is specifically for uploading a LIST of Objects. Im not sharing any code since I have nothing to show. I shared what I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data in the Firestore can be sent only as a `Map` object. So, you need to convert your `CartItem` object in the form of `Map`.

You can do this by creating a method `toJson()` as follows:

```
class CartItem {
  String name;
  double singlePrice;
  double quantity;

  CartItem({
    this.name,
    this.singlePrice,
    this.quantity,
  });

  dynamic toJson() => {
    'name': name,
    'singlePrice': singlePrice,
    'quantity': quantity,
  };

  factory CartItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return CartItem(
      name: json['name'],
      singlePrice: json['singlePrice'],
      quantity: json['quantity'],
    );
  }
}
```

The `toJson` method will allow you to convert your `CartItem` object in `Map` object that can be uploaded to Firebase.

The `fromJson` method will allow you to convert the data from Firebase back into `CartItem` object.

For uploading data to Firebase, you can do as follows:

Let's say you have

```
List<CartItem> _cart = [ CartItem(...), CartItem(...), ...];
```

Then, you can call the `toJson` method over each object & upload it to Firebase.

```
Future<void> _uploadCartToFirebase(List<CartItem> cartList) async {
  for(CartItem cartItem in cartList) {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('OrderID').doc()
                                       .set(cartItem.toJson());
  }
}
```

In case you want cartList back from Firebase:

```
Future<List<CartItem>> _getCartList() async {
  final querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.
                                collection('OrderID').get();
  List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> docs = querySnapshot.docs;
  final cartList = docs.map((doc) => 
                   CartItem.fromJson(doc.data())).toList();
  return cartList;
}
```

Comment: .set(cartList.toJson());

it says .toJson() is not defined for the list CartList....

Comment: Sorry, it should be `cartItem`. I will update the answer.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhh you mean .set(cartItem.toJson());!!
 IT WORKS!!!!!!! THANKSSSSSSSSS PAL!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Hi, Can you explain your Get data back from Firebase function a bit more?
What does `final querySnapshot` actually do? cuz it isn't referenced anywhere. Thanks!

Comment: Please check the updated answer. `docs = querySnapshot.docs;`